# Options for inter-service one-way communication

Tags: c++, com, windows-services

I'm searching for different options for implementing communication between a service and other services/applications.

**What I would like to do**:

I have a service that is constantly running, polling a device connected to a serial port. At certain points, this service should send a message to interested clients containing data retrieved from the device. Data is uncomplicated, most likely just a single string.

Ideally, the clients would not have to subscribe to receive these messages, which leads me to some sort of event 'broadcast' setup (similar to Windows events). The message sending process should not block, and does not need a response from any clients (or that there even are any clients for that matter).

I've been reading about IPC (COM in particular) and windows events, but am yet to come across something that really fits with what I want to do.

So is this possible? If so, what technologies should I be using? If not, what are some viable communication alternatives?

Here's the particulars of the setup:

- Windows 2000/XP environments
- 'Server' service is a windows service, using VC++2005
- Clients would vary, but always be in the windows environment (usual clients would be VC++6 windows services, VB6 applications)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the clients and servers in the same machine?

Comment: Yes, they'll all be on the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do a broadcast system, but you'll have to either give up reliability (ie, some messages must be lost) *or* use a proper subscription system.

If you're willing to give up reliability, you can create a shared memory segment and named manual-reset event object. When a new message arrives, write it to the shared memory segment, signal the event object, then close the event object and create a new one with a different name (the name should be in the shmem segment somewhere). Clients open the shmem segment, find the current event object, wait for it to be signaled, then read off the message and new event segment.

In this option, you must be careful to deal with the case of a client reading at the same time as the shmem segment is updated properly. One way to do this is to have two sequence number fields in the shmem segment - one is updated before the new message is written, one after. Clients read the *second* sequence number *prior* to reading the message, then re-read both sequence numbers after, and check that they are all equal (and discard the message and retry after a delay if they are not). Be sure to place memory barriers around accesses to these sequence numbers to ensure the compiler does not reorder them!

Of course, this is all a bit hairy. [Named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are a lot simpler, but a subscription (of a sort) is required. The server calls [`CreateNamedPipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then accepts connections with [`ConnectNamedPipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Clients use [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365144%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to connect to the server's pipe. The server then just loops to send data (using `WriteFile`) to all of its clients. Note that you will need to create addititonal instance of the pipe using `CreateNamedPipe` each time you accept a connection. An example of a named pipe server can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365588(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Great post, thanks. I was considering a shared memory option, is this viable when access is required from a VB6 application?

Comment: No. VB6 will not be able to work with shared memory very easily (if at all) unless you add a C library or activex control to deal with the shmem segment. Better to use named pipes, you should be able to use them with normal win32 api bindings.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer despite not actually using it. I went for a different approach which negated the requirement to broadcast events to clients. However I liked this answer, and it made me more intrigued about shared memory and the uses it could have. I'll probably end up implementing something using shared memory in the near future, so it was helpful describing some of the ways events could be triggered using it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows supports broadcasting messages, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#broadcasting). You can `SendMessage` to `HWND_BROADCAST` from the service, and receive it in each client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did come across this option but stumbled with the requirement to pass data and ability to send messages from a service (running as LOCALSYSTEM). I'll investigate further.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use blocking messaging functions, I envisage more of a 'fire-and-forget' system, as the server does not care about the client side usage of the data.

Comment: @Jack Smith: I can't think of a general communication mechanism that would allow to send an asynchronous data message to unknown recepients without having to bother with memory management. You could enumerate clients and post messages to them one-by-one, assuming that they will free the memory on their side, but this looks quite like "registering" which you'd like to avoid.

Comment: @Jack Smith: Oh, forget my previous comment about `SendMessage`, I don't know what I was thinking :) You'll still need to manage memory in this case, you could use WM_COPYDATA but I guess this will require enumerating the listeners again...